# sources.list file malformed Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: apt

Now I get this error:

```
WARNING:root:could not open file '/etc/apt/sources.list'
```

I would somehow like to get my original file back, plus some good instructions about how to install R that won't corrupt it.

---

ok - copied old version. Looks like the version after some program copied in the sources for the R package. Now get error:

```
sudo apt-get update
E: Malformed entry 50 in list file /etc/apt/sources.list (absolute Suite Component)
E: The list of sources could not be read.
```

Here is the file - what I think are lines  49 - 51. (Got an error about too many links when I tried to include the whole file)

```
# deb-src http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu bionic-security universe
deb https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ apt update sudo
# deb-src https://cloud.r-project.org/bin/linux/ubuntu bionic-cran35/ sudo apt update
```

(The first and third line start with #)

---

Ok - now tried gedit with line numbers on as you suggested. Just deleted line 50. Now get update is running. Don't know if R will actually install but this solves the issue I posted here. How do I accept your answer? And thank you very much for all your help.

Comment: In `terminal`, do `sudo ls -al /etc/apt/sources.list.*`, and check the dates and sizes. If they're current enough, we can just copy one over to be sources.list. Show the list as an edit to your question. Also, `gedit` will show line numbers if you enable that in the prefs (and the plugin is enabed). Report back to @heynnema

Comment: I know this is an old answer, but it should still work.  https://askubuntu.com/questions/124017/how-do-i-restore-the-default-repositories

Comment: -rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 3396 Oct 23 12:21 /etc/apt/sources.list.old
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  171 Oct 23 22:31 /etc/apt/sources.list.save

/etc/apt/sources.list.d:
total 8
drwxr-xr-x 2 root root 4096 Apr 20  2018 .
drwxr-xr-x 6 root root 4096 Oct 23 22:30 ..

Answer (score 1):

From the comments...

In `terminal` do...

`sudo ls -al /etc/apt/sources.list.*`

answer:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 root root 3396 Oct 23 12:21 /etc/apt/sources.list.old 
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root  171 Oct 23 22:31 /etc/apt/sources.list.save
```

funny enough, they're both the same date, but sources.list.old is much larger than sources.list.save, so I suspect that's the one we need. Let's briefly look at each one...

`cd /etc/apt`           # change directory

`cat sources.list.old`  # view the .old file

`cat sources.list.save` # view the .save file

Does the .old file look more complete? If so, do this...

`sudo rm -i sources.list`                # remove the old empty sources.list

`sudo cp sources.list.old sources.list`  # copy over a replacement

`sudo apt-get update`                    # update the software database

- you shouldn't get any errors on this last step. If you do, put a list of the errors as an edit to your question... not in the comments, please.